# 16.04 PHPmyadmin MySQL Unable to Insert Image

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I know I know, don't put images in the DB.  But I keep small thumbnails of book covers in a a small DB.  Now this worked fine up until some moron decided to steal my db and ask for bitcoin.

Ignoring the request for bitcoin, I got out the back up and restored it. So far so good, data is intact searches run beautifully.  Now when I finally got around to adding a new item, I find it will not let add images. It throws a wobbly with an error

```
Notice in ./tbl_replace.php#246
Undefined variable: message
```

The field is called "cover" and its a blob, with the default value of null, but even the null doesn't appear when you add an entry.

I see the field in the sql query is blank where the image files name ought to be, but that's all I know.  Can anyone help me solve this one?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere during the dump and the reload of the .sql file, the column lost the mime entry for image.  Stopping it doing anything with the field really.

A